# assign the individual string array values to a global array, it doesnt return anything

Tags: php

I have following code where `$accessEmailParams` is a string array. It works fine.

```
function processRequestAfterApproval($accessEmailParams) { 
  echo $accessEmailParams["reqFName"] . "<hr>";
  echo $accessEmailParams["reqLName"] . "<hr>";
  echo $accessEmailParams["reqWinID"] . "<hr>";
  echo $accessEmailParams["svWinID"] . "<hr>";
  echo $accessEmailParams["adminEmail"] . "<hr>";
  echo $accessEmailParams["current"] . "<hr>";
  echo $accessEmailParams["reqEmail"] . "<hr>";
  echo $accessEmailParams["svEmail"] . "<hr>"; 
}
```

But when i try to assign the individual string array values to a global array, it doesnt return anything. Please help.

```
function processRequestAfterApproval($accessEmailParams) {
  global $reqFName = $accessEmailParams["reqFName"];
  global $reqLName = $accessEmailParams["reqLName"];
  global $reqWinID = $accessEmailParams["reqWinID"];
  global $svWinID = $accessEmailParams["svWinID"];
  global $adminEmail = $accessEmailParams["adminEmail"];
  global $current = $accessEmailParams["current"];
  global $reqEmail = $accessEmailParams["reqEmail"];
  global $svEmail = $accessEmailParams["svEmail"];  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you declare the variables to be global, then you asign them, not at the same time, this will give a parse error.

Not:

```
global $reqFName = $accessEmailParams["reqFName"];
```

But:

```
global $reqFName ;
$reqFName = $accessEmailParams["reqFName"];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use

`$_GLOBALS['variablename'] = value`

To set it value and

`$_GLOBALS['variablename']`

To get it value.

Answer (score 0):

That would appear to be a syntax error, at least in PHP 5.4.12:

> Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or`';''

You need to declare the global on one line, and assign to it on another line:

```
function processRequestAfterApproval($accessEmailParams) {
  global $reqFName;
  $reqFName = $accessEmailParams["reqFName"];
}
```